# How can I keep a Timer running when the app is closed? (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a textView in my 2nd activity, that displays the time left (counting down from 24 hours) when the activity is started and navigates back to MainActivity when it is finished. However, when I close the app, this timer restarts. How would I make the timer continue to run, even when the app is closed and the user is not using it?

Some reference code would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
// timer
    object : CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            (millisUntilFinished / 1000).also { clock.text = it.toString() }
        }
        override fun onFinish() {
            "Done!".also { clock.text = it }
        }
    }.start()

    if(clock.text.toString().trim().contains("Done!")){
        val intent3 = Intent(this, MainActivity ::class.java)
        startActivity(intent3)
    }
```

Comment: you can do this by using a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: A service is how you run stuff in the background, but are you sure you want to? You're not going to force-pop open the app when the timer hits zero, right? It might be better to store the current "deadline" in shared preferences, and when the user opens the app again, you can retrieve that and start your ``Timer`` with however long's left, or show ``MainActivity`` if it's expired

Comment: @cactustictacs The timer is 24 hours, and it needs to be running the whole time. If I were to store it in sharedPreferences, it would require 24 hours on the app to finish, which is not the case in my scenario. If I misinterpreted your comment, please clarify.

Comment: @UmarzzstuSyed I'm assuming the app doesn't do anything if it's in the background when the time runs out, and it only opens the activity if the app is already open (or the next time you open it after the 24hrs has expired). If you work out the deadline time, you can just store that in the prefs, and start your timer running. If the user puts the app in the background, then you can restore the timer state next time they open the app, by checking if there's a deadline stored. And if it's already later than that, you can show the activity immediately. (Don't forget to clear the expired deadline)

Comment: What you mean by "it would require 24h on the app"? If your app doesn't need to perform an action when the timer stops you don't need a service, just save the `deadline` in sharedpreferences. if you need to perform an action, like sending data to the server (even if the user is not using the app) use a service, otherwise use sharedpreferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best thing you can do is create a Background service.
In this youtube video teach how to make a tamer with a background service
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvibl8YJfGo

And look at this code as a example:

```
package playstore.com.a02backgroundtimer;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Timer_Service extends Service {

    public static String str_receiver = "com.countdowntimerservice.receiver";

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    Calendar calendar;
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
    String strDate;
    Date date_current, date_diff;
    SharedPreferences mpref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    private Timer mTimer = null;
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 1000;
    Intent intent;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mpref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        mEditor = mpref.edit();
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        mTimer = new Timer();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 5, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
        intent = new Intent(str_receiver);
    }


    class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                    Log.e("strDate", strDate);
                    twoDatesBetweenTime();

                }

            });
        }

    }

    public String twoDatesBetweenTime() {


        try {
            date_current = simpleDateFormat.parse(strDate);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {
            date_diff = simpleDateFormat.parse(mpref.getString("data",""));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        try {


            long diff = date_current.getTime() - date_diff.getTime();
            int int_hours = Integer.valueOf(mpref.getString("hours", ""));

            long int_timer = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(int_hours);
            long long_hours = int_timer - diff;
            long diffSeconds2 = long_hours / 1000 % 60;
            long diffMinutes2 = long_hours / (60 * 1000) % 60;
            long diffHours2 = long_hours / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;


            if (long_hours > 0) {
                String str_testing = diffHours2 + ":" + diffMinutes2 + ":" + diffSeconds2;

                Log.e("TIME", str_testing);

                fn_update(str_testing);
            } else {
                mEditor.putBoolean("finish", true).commit();
                mTimer.cancel();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer.purge();


        }

        return "";

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e("Service finish", "Finish");
    }

    private void fn_update(String str_time) {

        intent.putExtra("time", str_time);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the recommended way to run things when the app is not running is to use the [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreground service to achieve the bahviour
https://proandroiddev.com/bound-and-foreground-services-in-android-a-step-by-step-guide-5f8362f4ae20

Comment: I want the timer to run in the background without displaying a notification, which I believe foreground services do.

Comment: You can't do it without foreground service because normal service will be killed after 15 - 30 secs.